# TypeError with string formatting when using __unicode__() in model for Django app

Tags: python, django, unicode, models

I'm working on only my second tutorial for creating a Django project and app. The first tutorial I completed was on djangoproject.com and I created the ever popular "Polls" app. That first tutorial specified that "it’s important to add `__str__()` methods to your models", but it also stated that "on Python 2, you should define `__unicode__()` methods returning unicode values instead." I'm running Python 2.7.9, and I successfully used `__unicode__()` in that first tutorial. I'm having trouble with the string formatting in the second tutorial that I'm currently working on, which is at effectivedjango.com.

Here is what worked for the first tutorial:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.question_text
```

And here is what I've unsuccessfully tried for the second tutorial:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I've also tried `return u'%s' + ' ' + '%s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)`, and `return u'%s' + u' ' + u'%s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)`.

When I try to create a `Question` object in my database using any of the above attempts, I keep getting `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. What am I doing wrong with the string formatting? I'm very new to Python, and coding period (in case you couldn't tell), so please "talk slowly and clearly" and "go easy on me" when giving any answers. Thanks!

Comment: I am a little confused. You think there is something wrong with the Contact class but when you try to create a Question object it gives you the type error? Also, how are you creating the question object?

Comment: I'm using the python shell in the Windows Command Prompt to create my Question and Contact objects. Funny thing, I just tried to create a Contact object again just now for the first time today, and it worked fine. And now I can't replicate whatever I was doing last night that kept giving me the TypeError. Thanks anyway for your help @Cheng, but it looks like everything is working fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear it works now :D

Answer (score -1):

Hmm. This seems to look correctly. Is it possible that you have some Contact()-entries stored in your database which don't contain a first_name or